# UITableView's height its content with Auto Layout but limit UITableView height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITableView` and `UIButton` in a `UIViewController`.

```
UIViewController -> UIView -> UITableView
                           -> UIButton
```

The `UITableView` height is set to change accordingly to its intrinsic content size. When there are more number of row in UITableView the height is increasing but i don't want to increase such that `UIButton` should not be visible. I don't want to have `UIScrollView` either in that `UIViewController`. The constraint for UIButton is set as 25pixel from bottom, 25pixel from UITbaleView and width is set to 70% of screen width. I have constraint set for UITableView as 10pixel from top, width same as superview and height set to 590. I am not sure how to set the priority so that UIButton will be visible even if there are more number of rows in UITableView.

I am using below code to increase the height of UITableView

```
override func updateViewConstraints() {
        tableViewHeight.constant = TableIb.contentSize.height
        super.updateViewConstraints()
    }
```

Comment: If you have no UI elements between the table view and the button, it's not clear why you are not simply setting the table view's bottom 25-pts from the top of the button?

Comment: @DonMag yes its set to 25pts above button. There is not UI elements between table view and button.

Comment: OK - so, why are you trying to use a "changing height" table view?

Comment: I want the button to be at bottom of tableview everytime. For e.g., when there is a only one row and row height is 60pts then button should be at 85pts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constrain your button:

- 25-pts from tableView bottom
- bottom lessThanOrEqualTo -25-pts from view bottom (safe-area)

Give your tableViewHeight constraint a Priority of less-than-required.

So, for example:

```
    button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.bottomAnchor, constant: 25.0).isActive = true
    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -25.0).isActive = true
    
    // whatever you want to start your tableView height at...
    //  it doesn't really matter, as I assume you'll be immediately
    //  changing its .constant value
    tableViewHeight = tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0)
    tableViewHeight.priority = .defaultHigh
    tableViewHeight.isActive = true
```

The button will "stick" 25-pts from the bottom of the tableView, and when you change `tableViewHeight.constant` it will "push the button down" but only until it is 25-pts from the bottom of the view (the safe-area).

As a side-note, get into the habit of referring to **Points** instead of **Pixels**, and **view width** instead of **screen width**.

---

Alternatively, embed your button in a `UIView` and set that view as the `viewForFooterInSection`. It will "stick" to the bottom row in the tableView, but remain visible when the tableView needs to scroll.

That would allow you to avoid the need to keep re-sizing your tableView.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to do it using greaterThanOrEqualTo constraint for the button.